# Overlapping ticks and figure not centered with matlab2tikz

Tags: pgfplots, floats, horizontal-alignment, ticks

See the printscreen. What I want is that the figure is centered, now that is not the case with using `\setlength\figurewidth{1.0\textwidth}`. Besides that the ticks with negative signs on the x-axis are overlapping.
How can I solve these issues?
Thanks :)

How it now looks:

[image]

Code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
%scale only axis, % Commented out as suggested in the answer
xmin=-2000,
xmax=500,
ymin=-1000,
ymax=400,
xtick={-1600,-1200,-800,-400,0,400}, % Now added to solve
ytick={-800,-400,0,400} % Now added
]
\addplot [color=red,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
0.198854299827786   -3.4314342957753e-05\\
0.390189269262637   0.000572951530544596\\
0.580159224048429   0.00169575075199724\\
0.776528090033777   0.00282710506604467\\
0.984098727468267   0.00371200672468541\\
```

Comment: Can you post your resulting tikz code? those negative signs look like endashes. Might be the viewer too.

Comment: I added the resulting code

Answer (score 1):

By default, *matlab2tikz* produces the code that enable `scale only axis` option of the axis environment (see *4.10.1 Common Scaling Options* of the pgfplots documentation). Just remove  that line from your .tikz file to solve the first issue. The second problem is more about your personal representation of the data, so I may only suggest to reduce the font or change the units. Hope it will help.